# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '32 85 70 6 11

Tags: python, pycharm

As the title briefly describes, I am trying to take the numbers in the numbers.txt file and read then calculate them using the statistics import. However when I read the line of integers "32 85 70 6 11 ..." and try to append them, it gives me a error message stating ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '32 85 70 6 11. I am very confused and would appreciate any help, thank you all!

```
import statistics as stat

num = []

with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        num.append(int(line))

mean = stat.mean(num)
median = stat.median(num)
mode = stat.mode(num)
variance = stat.variance(num)
standard_deviation = stat.stdev(num)

print("mean: ", mean)
print("median: ", median)
print("mode: ", mode)
print("variance: ", variance)
print("standard deviation: ", standard_deviation)
```

Comment: That looks like multiple different integers, not a single one

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you are reading a line of integers rather than a single one.
You'll want to `split` that line on every space:

```
line.split("")
```

which will give you a list of strings.

So for your code it looks like this:

```
import statistics as stat

num = []

with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        numbers = [int(number) for number in line.split()]  # Changes here
        num.extend(numbers)                                    # And here

mean = stat.mean(num)
median = stat.median(num)
mode = stat.mode(num)
variance = stat.variance(num)
standard_deviation = stat.stdev(num)

print("mean: ", mean)
print("median: ", median)
print("mode: ", mode)
print("variance: ", variance)
print("standard deviation: ", standard_deviation)
```

Notice that since I've used a list comprehension for `numbers` it is a list of ints. Therefore I had to use the `extend` method which adds all the elements in a list, rather than the `append` method which would have added the whole list as a single element.

Comment: line 6, in <module>
    numbers = [int(number) for number in line.split(" ")]
line 6, in <listcomp>
    numbers = [int(number) for number in line.split(" ")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error plz?

Comment: I solved it by removing the " " in line.split(" ")

Comment: Edited my answer to remove the space. Don't forget to validate.

Answer (score 0):

The integers are separated by a whitespace, python does not know that, so one way to read in the data properly is:

```
num =[]
with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        s = [int(n) for n in line.split(" ")]
        num.extend(s)
```

`line.split(" ")` returns a list with all the numbers in the line as strings, so we convert each number to an integer with `int(n)` and add them to the list `num`. Then you can do the rest of what you want.

Comment: line 6, in <module>
    numbers = [int(number) for number in line.split(" ")]
line 6, in <listcomp>
    numbers = [int(number) for number in line.split(" ")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Can you post an example of what line is?

Answer (score 0):

piggy backing off what the others have said, I had to remove the " " in line.split(" ") to achieve the desired result

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        numbers = [int(number) for number in line.split()]
        num.extend(numbers)
```